# Formatting is off with cancel to package

Tags: formatting, cancel

I am trying to use the cancel package when showing a term is zero and therefore can be discounted. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
$\Gamma_{yy}^x = \frac{1}{2}g^{xa}\left[- g_{yy,a} + \cancelto{0}{g_{xy,a}} + \cancelto{0}{g_{yx,a}}\right]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However I feel like the formatting could be improved but don't know how to go about it. Is there anyway to make the arrow steeper in this case so it doesn't overlap with the operator or the brackets? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 1 of the documentation for `cancelto` we read

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}

$\Gamma_{yy}^x =
  \frac{1}{2}g^{xa}[- g_{yy,a} + \cancelto{0}{g_{xy,a}} + \cancelto{0}{g_{yx,a}}]$

\end{document}
```

[image]